# How can I open the web app inside a server in my company from my home?

Tags: vpn, lan, ssh-tunnel

There are 2 Linux servers in my company (Let's call them A, and B).

A and B are located in a [Local Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network). They don't have public IP addresses. They can send packets to each other using private IP addresses such as `172.27.X.X`.

My company only allows us to establish a VPN connection to server A using [AnyConnect](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html) when we are at home.

Now there's a web app hosting on server B. How can I open the web app using my browser when I'm at home?

The web app on server B listens to port 80 and 443.

I'm able to view web apps on server A when the VPN connection is established. But don't know if it's possible to use server A to get access to the web app on server B.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution to this is [SSH port forwarding AKA SSH tunneling](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

To build a tunnel from your local port 8080 to port 80 on remote server B through remote host  A, simply do:

```
ssh -L 8080:<host-B-IP>:80  username@<host-A-IP>
```

For port 443 on server B:

```
ssh -L 8443:<host-B-IP>:443  username@<host-A-IP>
```

Afterwards, you can just open the website using `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8443`.